# Cannot add basic class to project from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, unity-game-engine

I used to be able to add basic empty classes from visual studio in my Unity solution. But that option does not even show up anymore. I updated to VS2017 a while back, maybe that is the issue or perhaps the newer Unity integrates "better" with VS nowadays. I can always add a C# script from unity but I liked adding classes from VS and would be glad if I can have that option back.

[image: Cannot add basic item types]

Comment: Did you take a look to the "Online" items ? (left panel, under "Installed")

Comment: @Hellium What should I look for? I tried searching a basic "class.cs" without any luck. I figured I should already have it but something is hiding it.

Comment: I've never faced this problem. I just suggested this without knowing if it would work. You should try to run the [Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio) and make sure the C# support is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to open the VS installer. After it updated I could pick modify on my current VS 2017 instance and noticed the .NET package was not active and neither was any other package. Adding that solved my issue. I'm sure I have been using the basic templates in conjunction with Unity before, perhaps I uninstalled it by accident or it uninstalled along with removing VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen after a recent upgrade from VS 2017 to VS 2019. 
I did have .NET installed.  So I used the installer to uninstall .NET, then again to reinstall .NET.  It asked for a reboot, and finally I was able to add a simple class again.